# standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: python, linux, azure, docker

I am currently trying to deploy my docker application to the container registry Azure. I am able to run my docker image locally but when I deploy it to azure, it gives me this error:

standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
 Here is my dockerfile:

```
*Pull a pre-built alpine docker image with nginx and python3 installed

*this image is from docker community, its small so our upload to contain will be faster

FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.7

FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8400

EXPOSE 8400

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y /

    curl apt-utils apt-transport-https debconf-utils gcc build-essential g++-5\

    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

*adding custom MS repository

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

*install SQL Server drivers

RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -f install -y unixodbc-dev

*install SQL Server tools

RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools

RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev

*install additional requirements from a requirements.txt file

COPY requirements.txt /

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

COPY app/. /.

CMD python3 wsgi.py
```

Because I do not understand how azure calls my Docker images, I kept on trying different CMD versions such as:

CMD ["python3", "wsgi.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8400"]

But to no avail. I looked up on internet for solutions but really could not find any. Is there anyone there that has insights on what I do wrong? Is it essential to create a .sh file ? I am new to linux so any insights will help!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've experienced similar issues that was caused by the docker image being built on one architecture (say AMD64) but then failed when trying to run on a different architecture (ARM64).
Look into QEMU
[tutorial](https://lobradov.github.io/Building-docker-multiarch-images/)

[docker ref](https://engineering.docker.com/2019/04/multi-arch-images/)

Comment: Hi Evan, thank you very much for your reply! I have looked at the azure architecture which is AMD64 and my docker is also AMD64. But I actually solved my problem! its because of the lack of shebang at my py file. But thanks for the time to reply :) I really appreciate it

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. I was building my image on an ARM64 machine and getting this error. I rebuilt it for AMD64 using [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) and that fixed it.