# Azure IOTEdge - Raspberry Pi 4 (standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error")

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-instances

I am trying to follow the `https://github.com/Azure/ai-toolkit-iot-edge/blob/master/IoT%20Edge%20anomaly%20detection%20tutorial/00-anomaly-detection-tutorial.ipynb` tutorial. The one difference is that I am pushing to a Raspberry Pi 4. The `edgeHub` and `edgeAgent` start fine but my container `machinelearningmodule` fails.

```
sudo docker logs -f machinelearningmodule
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I have looked at this github issue which suggests using `arm64v8/python` images https://github.com/emqx/emqx-docker/issues/108.

However when I put this into the code...

```
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(runtime= "python",
                                 execution_script="iot_score.py",
                                 conda_file="myenv.yml",
                                 tags = {'area': "iot", 'type': "classification"},
                                 description = "IOT Edge anomaly detection demo",
                                 base_image = 'arm64v8/python'
                                                 )
```

I get  the following error:

```
Step 2/25 : FROM arm64v8/python
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
latest: Pulling from arm64v8/python
2020/02/18 17:48:41 Container failed during run: acb_step_0. No retries remaining.
```

So guessing that is a dead end. Any suggestions on where to go from here?

p.s. also tried this 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000007/standard-init-linux-go207-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error`
doesn't work either sadly.

Comment: Hey have you find a solution?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/Azure/ai-toolkit-iot-edge/issues/24, I would be so happy if you could give me an answer...